# sqlite3: can I safely wait with commit()

Tags: python, sqlite

I insert 10,000,000+ records into a sqlite base. Is it safe that I wait with `connection.commit()` until I finish all the insertions? Or there is some out of memory/overflow risk? Is it possible that the uncommitted entries will use all the available memory and cause page swapping? Committing after each `INSERT` is a performance killer, so I want to avoid it.

I use [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) module with Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the first place, sqlite is not really meant to handle that much data. It is generally for smaller data sets. However, committing that much data might take longer when committing all at once then if you were to commit say after every 2 or 3 inserts.

As far as your memory/overflow risk, sqlite dumps everything into a file chache then on commit put's all the file cache into the sqlitedb file.

However, committing all at once *shouldnt* give you any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Committing all the insertions at once is a perfectly acceptable optimization. If an error *should* occur (which is unlikely) then it will occur within the client library, and at that point you can look into solving that issue. But worrying about that prematurely is unnecessary.

Comment: To make it more precise: is it possible that the uncommitted entries will use all the available memory and cause page swapping? I am concerned because the data processing lasta for hours, and the performance losses will add additional hours... (eventually I will commit every 10k inserts or so)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's [rollback journal](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) stores the old contents of all pages that were changed in the database file.

If you are only inserting data, you are not actually changing much data that already is in the database (only some management structures), so there will not accumulate much overhead data for the transaction.

(The situation would be different if you had enabled [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).)